# Nutch Recrawl - Storing segments is necessory or not

Tags: nutch

I am deleting segments after they gets indexed then how nutch will get that last fetch time of pages while recrawling?  Do i need to store them to speedup the recrawl?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last fetch time is maintained by crawldb and not segments. Segments are useful just from indexing & searching perspective. Storing in any from will NOT impact crawling rate.